# Silverlight 5 - How can I use plain CLR Objects in XAML as a CommandParameter?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, parameters, command, clr

I would like to know, if it is possible, to use simple C# CLR Objects as a Command Parameter in XAML, like I do it with MarkupExtensions.

For example, I use my own Markup Extension, which looks like this:

```
public class FormOpenExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public eForm e { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

The use of the MarkupExtension in XAML looks like this:

```
CommandParameter="{gui:FormOpen e=Login}
```

In XAML, I have full intellisense support for the FormOpenExtension Object , compiling is no problem. So this works like a charm.

### ---------------------------------------

Now I have a simple CLR Object, that for example looks like this:

```
namespace DB
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class User
    {
        #region Primitive Properties

        [Key][DataMember]
        public virtual int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
}
```

I can import the namespace into XAML and use the object, including intellisense like this:

```
CommandParameter="{db:User ID=1, Name=Foo}
```

Visual Studio says, I am using the User object like a MarkupExtension, but it is none.

**I fully understand the problem.** The plain User Object is no Extension.

What I don't get, is how to use the User Object as a Command Parameter, without writing my own Extension.

**So here are my 2 concrete questions:**

1.) Is it possible to use my own objects in XAML, without wrapping them into a Extension?

2.) If yes, what would be the correct syntax for a Command Parameter?

Thank you.

### ----------------------------------

Ok, thank you Dimitri. Here is the solution, as it worked for me now:

Step 1) Import the namespace

```
xmlns:db="clr-namespace:DB"
```

Step 2) Using the CLR object as a static resource.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <db:User x:Key="User"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Step 3) Pass the Object Key, in this case User, to the CommandParameter

```
CommandParameter="{StaticResource User}
```

Step 4) Bind the User Object to the desired controls in your UserConrol

```
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource User}, Path=EMail, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand question, [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) can help to find solution.

p.s. what about simple declaring object as resource and then use it via `StaticResource` extension.

```
<Resources>
     <DB:User Id="1" Name="Name" x:Key="User"/>
</Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will read through this and make a comment, if it helped me.

Comment: Well, as I said, I need this Object as a CommandParameter and I don't get the syntax for that.

Comment: Great, that is working. Is it possible to bind the Name Property of the User Object to a TextBox? Like: CommandParameter="{StaticResource User, Name=Textbox}"

Comment: U should use ViewModel and converters to implement your logic. it will be the best way. see MVVM pattern.